If $X, Y$ independent, and $Y$ has same distribution as $Z$, are $X, Z$ independent?
$$
\newcommand{\Prob}{\mathbb P}
$$
Let $(E, \mathcal E, \mathbb P)$ and $(F, \mathcal F)$ be a probability and measure space, respectively. Suppose we have the random variables $X, Y, Z \colon E \to F$. Further suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and that $Y$ has the same law as $Z$.
Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? I am not sure if this is true. Here is my attempt. For $A \in \sigma(X)$ and $B \in \sigma(Y)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\Prob\left( (X, Y) \in A \times B \right) &= \Prob( X \in A, Y \in B )\\
&= \Prob (X \in A) \Prob(Y \in B)\\
&= \Prob (X \in A) \Prob(Z \in B).
\end{align*}
I am not sure if this is correct so far, and I'm not sure how to continue.
Thanks for any help.

This is not true. Take $X$ and $Y$ i.i.d. and $Z=X$.
